# How to move FTP files to another directory in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, file-rename

I tried below code to move FTP files from one location to another location but I am facing issues.

**Code:**

```
Uri serverFile = new Uri("ftp://3.222.001.114/ftproot/Incomming/ProcessedFiles/Test.xml");
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP= (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverFile);
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "test123");
                reqFTP.RenameTo = "ftp://3.222.001.114/ftproot/Incomming/ProcessedFiles/Test/Test.xml";
                reqFTP.GetResponse().Close();
```

But I am getting below error:

> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550)
>   File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

IF any other way move FTP files.

Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://3.222.001.114/ftproot/Incomming/ProcessedFiles/Test.xml");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "test123");
request.RenameTo = "../Test/Test.xml";   //Relative path 
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is because FTP expects relative paths for `RenameTo`.   Try this:

```
Uri serverFile = new Uri("ftp://3.222.001.114/ftproot/Incomming/ProcessedFiles/Test.xml");
FtpWebRequest reqFTP= (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverFile);
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "test123");
reqFTP.RenameTo = "Test/Test.xml";
reqFTP.GetResponse().Close();
```